# Imposm does not create planet_osm_* tables

Tags: tilemill, imposm

I'm trying to follow the Tilemill [OSM-Bright tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-ubuntu-quickstart/) on a fresh install of OSGeoLive 8.0.

I followed the instructions in the tutorial, and when I run tilemill, it can't access planet_osm_polygons.

```
Postgis Plugin: ERROR:  relation "planet_osm_polygon" does not exist
LINE 2:   FROM planet_osm_polygon                 ^
```

...

Looking over the console from imposm, no planet_osm* tables are mentioned. Was imposm supposed to create this table?

```
~/Downloads$ imposm -U user -d osm -m ../osm_bright/mapbox-osm-bright-5f237ac/imposm-mapping.py --read --write --optimize --deploy-production-tables new-york_new-york.osm.pbf
loading ../osm_bright/mapbox-osm-bright-5f237ac/imposm-mapping.py as mapping
password for user at localhost:
[14:23:43] ## reading new-york_new-york.osm.pbf
[14:23:43] coords: 5144k nodes: 102k ways: 734k relations: 5k (estimated)
[14:27:26] coords: 8216k nodes: 18k ways: 1355k relations: 3k
[14:27:29] reading took 3 m 45s
[...
[14:42:33] ## optimizing tables
Clustering table osm_new_mainroads
Clustering table osm_new_buildings
```

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you have configured Tilemill for the importer `imposm` instead of `osm2pgsql`?

See  Step 3 point 3 of your tutorial:

```
3. Change config["importer"] = "osm2pgsql" to config["importer"] = "imposm", unless you prefer to use osm2pgsql and have that set up.
```

The table names of imposm are listed here: imposm.org/docs/imposm/latest/database_schema.html#tables

`planet_osm_polygon` is a table name used by osm2pgsql, hence can not be found in a database populated by imposm.

Comment: Oy, that could very well be correct! Thank you, I'll check tonight.